# Regex replace if matching group not preceded by `\` exept if preceded by `\\`

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, negative-lookbehind

### My Goal

What I want to do is something similar to this:

```js
let json_obj = {
    hello: {
        to: 'world'
    },
    last_name: {
        john: 'smith'
    },
    example: 'a ${type}', // ${type} -> json_obj.type 
    type: 'test'
}

// ${hello.to} -> json_obj.hello.to -> "word"
let sample_text = 'Hello ${hello.to}!\n' + 
    // ${last_name.john} -> json_obj.last_name.john -> "smith"
    'My name is John ${last_name.john}.\n' + 
    // ${example} -> json_obj.example -> "a test"
    'This is just ${example}!';

function replacer(text) {
    return text.replace(/\${([^}]+)}/g, (m, gr) => {
        gr = gr.split('.');
        let obj = json_obj;
        while(gr.length > 0)
          obj = obj[gr.shift()];
        /* I know there is no validation but it 
            is just to show what I'm trying to do. */
        return replacer(obj);
    });
}

console.log(replacer(sample_text));
```

Until now this is pretty easy to do.
But if `$` is preceded by a backslash(`\`) I don't want to replace the thing between brackets. For example: `\${hello.to}`would not be replaced.

The problem grows up when I want to be able to escape the backslashes. What I mean by escaping the backslashes is for example:

- `\${hello.to}` would become: `${hello.to}`
- `\\${hello.to}` would become: `\world`
- `\\\${hello.to}` would become: `\${hello.to}`
- `\\\\${hello.to}` would become: `\\${hello.to}`
- etc.

**What I've tried?**
I didn't try many thing so far cause I've absolutely no idea how to achieve that since from what I know there is no *lookbehind* pattern in javascript regular expressions.

I hope the way I explained it is clear enoughto be understood andI hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to solve this problem in separate steps :)

### 1) First step:

Simplify backslashes of your text replacing all occurrences of `"\\"` for `""`. This will eliminate all redundancies and make the token replacement part easier.

```
text = text.replace(/\\\\/g, '');
```

### 2) Second step:

To replace the tokens of the text, use this regex: `/[^\\](\${([^}]+)})/`. This one will not permit tokens that have with \ before them. Ex: \${hello.to}.

#### Here is you code with the new expression:

```
function replacer(text) {
    return text.replace(/[^\\](\${([^}]+)})/, (m, gr) => {
        gr = gr.split('.');
        let obj = json_obj;
        while(gr.length > 0)
          obj = obj[gr.shift()];
        /* I know there is no validation but it 
            is just to show what I'm trying to do. */
        return replacer(obj);
    });
}
```

If you still have any problems, let me know :)

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that I dont want to remove all the backslashes.

Comment: You don't need to change the main string. You can have an `originalText` and a `simplifiedText`. And make the token replacement using the simplified one.

Comment: The regex of your second step would not work if `${example}` is placed at the beginning of the string. Moreover, still in your second step you add a *group* so `gr` would be `${example}` instead of `example`

Comment: Oh! Great!I hadn't thought about that! But there is still the problem of your second step. do you think this regex would work `/([^\\]|\0)\${([^}]+)}/`?

Comment: Oops... Almost finishing the regex. Give me few minutes ^^

Comment: Try this one: `(^\${([^}]+)})|[^\\](\${([^}]+)})`. This worked here.

Comment: Thanks! I took your regex and removed the useless parentheses and I came with this final regex: `/^\${([^}]+)}|[^\\]\${([^}]+)}/g`